# How to check if certain plugin exists and in expected version

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I've created plugin that goes to wordpress plugin repositories. Now, I need to create another plugin (sub plugin or child plugin you may call) that require this certain plugin to be already installed and activated.

I know I can use `register_activation_hook`. However, how do I check using that hook? Or, maybe there's another solution exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`is_plugin_active()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) function.

Other method is to check if functions or classes, specific to required plugin, exist. Some plugins explicitly define their own constants for this, typically with version number and/or other identifying info.

There has been some developments to make extension dependence logic more generic, such as [Plugin Dependecies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-dependencies/), but they hadn't gained widespread adoption so far.

Comment: You may also need to add the `require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );` before you can use `is_plugin_active()`

Comment: Hey @rarst, the link doesn't work any more. Is there any updated version of the link?

Comment: @Mahmudur plugin had changed a lot since, so no newer example from it...