# My plugin does not install correctly if a previous version is still installed

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, upgrade, activation, deactivation

My plugin only installs correctly if the user first deactivates and then deletes a previously installed version.  If they do not delete the previous version, the installation either does not complete or the plugin, once installed, does not work.

Although it would be nice to get at the heart of why this is occurring, it seems like for best user experience anyway the plugin should automatically deactivate and remove previous versions upon installation.  Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if certain plugin exists and in expected version](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/how-to-check-if-certain-plugin-exists-and-in-expected-version)

Comment: @m0r7if3r That is certainly relevant and a part of my question, but I'm trying to get at how to deactivate and remove the old plugin before (or when) the new plugin installs

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy.

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-folder-name/main-plugin-file.php' ) )
    deactivate_plugins( '/plugin-folder-name/main-plugin-file.php' );
```

It's important to note the `is_plugin_active` string is *slightly* different than the `deactivate_plugins` string.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew!  This deactivates the plugin... would I then want to `uninstall_plugins( '/plugin-folder-name/main-plugin-file.php' );` ?