# How to stop activating a plugin and show admin notice when dependent plugins minimum version is not met

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, wp-dependencies

I have a plugin which is dependent on another plugin, in this case WooCommerce.

How can I stop the activation of my plugin and display an admin notice with download link of the dependent plugin, if the version of the dependent plugin is lower than a certain version?

In short, on the activation process my plugin should not be activated and display a notice with download link when any of the following is true:

1. WooCommerce plugin is not activated (I have solution for this)
2. The version of WooCommerce plugin is less than a certain version
   (I do not have solution for this)

**Note**: [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189208/check-for-dependent-plugin-and-if-false-dont-activate-plugin) is answering my question partially, but I need to have a full solution to check the version of the dependent plugin and display admin notice accordingly.

Comment: Your plugin must be active for the notice to be displayed, what you are asking for is not possible, but what you want is, if you perform your check in the plugin file then return early if the condition is not met before any of the other code runs, then you can have your admin notice. Similar checks are made in code that tests the version of PHP

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for the heads up. The answer I was looking for is here and it worked as I wanted. My plugin does not get activated and yet I get the notice I am looking for. Thanks to Fluent-Themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code in your plugin. I have used this in my ARB booking plugin and it worked perfectly. The full [details of the code with explanation can be found here](https://fluentthemes.com/best-way-to-abort-a-plugin-and-show-admin-notice-when-dependent-plugins-minimum-version-is-not-met/):

```
class FT_AdminNotice {
    
    protected $min_wc = '5.0.0'; //replace '5.0.0' with your dependent plugin version number
    
    /**
     * Register the activation hook
     */
    public function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'ft_install' ) );
    }
    
    /**
     * Check the dependent plugin version
     */
    protected function ft_is_wc_compatible() {          
        return defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) && version_compare( WC_VERSION, $this->min_wc, '>=' );
    }
    
    /**
     * Function to deactivate the plugin
     */
    protected function ft_deactivate_plugin() {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
        deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
            unset( $_GET['activate'] );
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Deactivate the plugin and display a notice if the dependent plugin is not compatible or not active.
     */
    public function ft_install() {
        if ( ! $this->ft_is_wc_compatible() || ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
            $this->ft_deactivate_plugin();
            wp_die( 'Could not be activated. ' . $this->get_ft_admin_notices() );
        } else {
            //do your fancy staff here
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Writing the admin notice
     */
    protected function get_ft_admin_notices() {
        return sprintf(
            '%1$s requires WooCommerce version %2$s or higher installed and active. You can download WooCommerce latest version %3$s OR go back to %4$s.',
            '<strong>' . $this->plugin_name . '</strong>',
            $this->min_wc,
            '<strong><a href="https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woocommerce.latest-stable.zip">from here</a></strong>',
            '<strong><a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) ) . '">plugins page</a></strong>'
        );
    }

}

new FT_AdminNotice();
```

You will get admin notice like this when your plugin is activated without the Dependent plugin’s desired version:
[image: Notice to activate desired version of the dependent plugin]

You see the admin notice has the download link of the dependent plugin and also the user can get back to the plugins page by clicking on the plugins page link.

Comment: it worked :) I pasted your chunk of code at the bottom of my plugin's index.php file and worked like magic. Now my plugin aborts the activation process if the dependent plugin is not active OR the version number of the dependent plugin does not met. Lots of thanks to you.